# Changing shape of numpy array with images

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have a NumPy array called `FLAIR_X` with 583 images. Each image can be extracted by using the index (e.g., `plt.imshow(FLAIR_X[0])`). Currently, the shape of the array is `(583,)`, but sklearn needs an array of size `(583, 224, 224)` (`(224,224)`being the size of a single image). This will also make it easier to work with. I tried doing :

```
temp = FLAIR_X.reshape(583, 224, 224)
```

But I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-4bb1899edbd8> in <module>
----> 1 temp = FLAIR_X.reshape(583, 224, 224)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 583 into shape (583,224,224)
```

How can I reshape this array, so that is meets the requirements?

P.S: Just an extra question, will I be able to display images like earlier (`plt.imshow(FLAIR_X[0])`) after I reshape the data?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the type of your `image`?

Comment: It is a NumPy array with shape `(224, 224)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply calling:

```
res = np.array(FLAIR_X)
```

If that does not help, try:

```
l = FLAIR_X.tolist()
res = np.array(l)
```

If that does not help either, I don't believe your elements are numpy arrays.